# Secondary Y-asix in asp.net-mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mschart

I am creating chart in `asp.net-mvc4`application. Previous I had only one y-axis on the left side of the chart but now I want to add another y-axis on the right side of the chart. My code for only primary `y-axis` is

```
public ActionResult PreviewChart(long id = 0, string Kanal = "")
    {
        ChartData returnValue = new ChartData();

        if (id != 0 & Kanal != "")
        {
            returnValue = SearchRepository.FillChart(id, Kanal);
        }

        var c = new Chart(width: 700, height: 420)
           .AddTitle(returnValue.Name)

           .AddSeries("Default", markerStep: 4, chartType: "Line", xValue:   
               returnValue.xData, yValues: returnValue.yData)
           .SetXAxis(returnValue.xUnit)
           .SetYAxis(returnValue.yUnit)
           .GetBytes("png");


      return File(c, "image/png");


    }
```

Amd the code in view is, `Messungen` is the name of the controller

```
<td width = "50%">
  <p><img src = "@Url.Action("PreviewChart", "Messungen", new { id = Model.ID, Kanal = ViewBag.Kanal }, null)"  /></p>
</td>
```

Now I have edited the code for second `y-axis`. I have put random values here just for test, I am not getting from the data server.

```
public ActionResult PreviewChart(long id = 0, string Kanal = "")
    {


        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();

        var lines = new Series("lines");
        lines.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        lines.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 20));
        lines.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 30));
        lines.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 34));
        lines.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
        chart1.Series.Add(lines);

        var branches = new Series("branches");
        branches.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        branches.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 5));
        branches.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 6));
        branches.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 8));
        branches.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
        chart1.Series.Add(branches);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            chart1.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
        }

       // return File(c, "image/png");

        //==============================================

        //==============================================

    }
```

The problem is that application does show plot. I have not made any change in the view of the controller.

Comment: have you enabled the secondary Y-axe ? : chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True. Secondary: you have to attribute a serie to a chartArea : branches.ChartArea="NameOfChartArea"